# Opt lock and OneToMany realtion

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have 2 Entities:

```
Package{
    @OneToMany(fetch = EAGER, mappedBy = "package")
    private List<PackageVersion> PackageVersions;
}

PackageVersion{
    private state;  

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Package package;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "optlock")
    private Long optLock;

}
```

The version can be in different states (Draft,Live). I wont to have at most one DRAFT package version for a package.

The problem scenario is when multiple concurrent threads (nodes) are tying to create a new DRAFT version. They will succeed.

I'll tried to push the opt lock to the Package and annotated the save method with *@Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)* but that did not help.

Any suggestion how to prevent multiple DRAFT creation?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by moving the optlock to the Package and added a timestamp field on it.

This way I always have a change to the Package so the optlock is incremented by hibernate.